# Add a seekbar in preferences

Tags: android

I've made a preference-list. I get it from the code

```
 addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferencelayout);
```

This gets me to my `preferencelayout.xml` file as contains the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<PreferenceCategory android:title="Settings">
<ListPreference
   android:key="listPref"
   android:title="Shake sensitivity"
   android:summary=""
   android:entries="@array/listArray"
   android:entryValues="@array/listValues"
   android:defaultValue="165" />


   <SeekBarPreference
   android:defaultValue="22"
   android:title="Set the default time"
   android:key="seekBar">
   </SeekBarPreference>

 <CheckBoxPreference
   android:key="checkboxPref"
   android:title="Autodecrease music"
   android:summary=""
   android:defaultValue="true"/>
 </PreferenceCategory>
 </PreferenceScreen>
```

When I press the SeekBarPreference button, a dialog comes up with the Seekbar and with 2 buttons, save and cancel!

Here comes my question:

Can I add a textview or something to be shown beside the seekbar to view which value that the seekbar is currently pointing at?

How can I get the value the user has entered?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You would get the value from the [`OnSeekBarChangeListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener).

Comment: FYI: the above link is a dead link (404).

Comment: Note however that the value from `OnSeekBarChangeListener` will only get updated when the user takes their finger off the seekbar. You can see this odd behavior in Android system's own bright seekbar in your phone settings. The only value that gets updated regardless whether user has their finger on or not is the one you get on the right-end after you add `app:showSeekBarValue="true"`

Answer (score 0):

This will capture the ontouch listener of the seekbar and will change the text of the textview based on the change in value of the seekbar.

```
SeekBar bar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekbar);
bar.setOnTouchListener(new SeekBar.OnTouchListener()
{
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent arg1)
    {
        View parent = (View)v.getParent();
        TextView textView = (TextView)parent.findViewById(R.id.seekbarProgress);
        if (textView != null)
        {
            SeekBar seekBar = (SeekBar)v;
            int progress = seekBar.getProgress();
            textView.setText(seekBar.getProgress() + "/" + seekBar.getMax());
        }
        return false;
     }
});
```

Comment: thanks for your answer! the findviewbyid for the seekbar i think it should be(R.xml.preferencelayout)
what about the textview, where should i declare it? in the same xml as the seekbar?

Comment: Yes, the textview should be declared in the same xml as the seekbar. To make the textview appear on the right side of the seekbar, I would recommend you to use relativeLayout so that you can use the 'android:layout_toRightOf="@id/listviewSeekBar"' feature.

Answer (score 0):

Now, Android supports this behavior out-of-the-box just add below line to your `SeekBarPreference`:

```
   app:showSeekBarValue="true"
```

Comment: Unfortunately it's not localized. Meaning it only shows english numerals.